# Derivation of Rice's distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, transformation

I am confused with the derivation of the Rice's distribution. The resulting density of the sum of two squared normal random variables is the chi-squared density. Yet, when deriving the Rice's distribution as, $$ R= \sqrt{X_1^{2} + X_2^{2}} $$ that is, transforming a chi-squared distribution using $$ f(r) = \sqrt{u} $$ where $$ u \sim \chi $$ does not arrive to the known Rice's distribution. Indeed, the derivation makes use of the multiplication of two independent random variables, and then, transforming them from Cartesian to polar.

The proof I see is shown in the link below, and it seems it is the usual proof. ftp://ftp.bartol.udel.edu/anita/amir/Rician_Distribution_notes.pdf

Comment: I don't understand your complaint. If $\nu=0,\,\sigma=1$ [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution#Characterization) the PDF is $x\exp\frac{-x^2}{2}$ on its support $x\ge0$. [This matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution#Probability_density_function) the $\chi_2$ PDF.

Comment: the question is why the Rice's distribution is derived as the product of two independent Normal variables and not and the transformation of the Chi-squared distribution, taking into account that there is the sum of two squared Normal variables.

Comment: Could you edit in this derivation, or a link to it?

Comment: Updated the question with a link to one solution I have found, yet, it seems it is the usual way to proof it.

Comment: You may need to point to which part is confusing. I'm sorry, I don't see a [product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables) anywhere in your link, be it of independent variables or otherwise. I *do* see a factor being pulled out of an integral when proving (7). That's not remotely the same thing, but if it's what you'd like explained just let me know.

Comment: I think I have understood the reason. I have felt short of the basic concept that both $$X_1 \text{and} X_2$$ do not share the support and therefore their distribution cannot be convolved but only multiplied as these are independent random variables. I will still leave the question, maybe someone else would ask herself the same question...

Comment: thanks J.G., the step (5) shows the product of two Normal variables. Yet, since both lie in different spaces and they are  independent, the step is justified. My mad from the beginning.

Comment: @ngbacher Right. [Their PDFs multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case); the variables themselves don't.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can use a variable transformation; you're just transforming the wrong distribution. Let $f(z) = \sqrt{x}$ where $x$ is a random variable sampled from a chi-square distribution with two-degrees of freedom. The pdf of $x$ is:

$$p_x(x) = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \exp{\left(\frac{-x}{2\sigma^2}\right)}  \;\; (x\geq 0)$$
Simplifying the steps of the transformation, the pdf of $f(z)$ is:
$$p_z(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\left[\int_0^{z^2}p_x(x)dx\right]  = 2|z| \cdot p_x(z^2) =  \frac{z}{\sigma^2} \exp{\left(\frac{-z^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}, \;\; (z\geq 0) $$
which is the Rayleigh distribution, not the Rician.

In order to arrive at the Rician we have to consider Gaussians with ***non-zero*** means. Let's instead transform a non-central chi-square distribution (with two-degrees of freedom). The pdf of $x$ is now:

$$p_x(x) = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \exp{\left(-\frac{x+\nu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)} I_0\left(\frac{\nu\sqrt{x}}{\sigma^2} \right)  \;\; (x\geq 0)$$

where $\nu^2 = \mu_1^2 + \mu_2^2$ is the magnitude square of the two means and $I_0$ is the zero'th-order modified Bessel function of the first kind. Again, letting $f(z) = \sqrt{x}$ we can repeat the derivation and find the pdf of $f(z)$ to be:

$$p_z(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\left[\int_0^{z^2}p_x(x)dx\right]  = 2|z| \cdot p_x(z^2) =  \frac{z}{\sigma^2} \exp{\left(-\frac{z^2+\nu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)} I_0\left(\frac{\nu z}{\sigma^2} \right), \;\; (z\geq 0) $$
Which is the desired Rician Distribution.